PowerShell - AzureAD Report Export
I was able to find this AzureAD script below which can help me export Azure users into a CSV file using Powershell. I was hoping if someone can help me adjust it, so that it is also filtering by Country or Region in Azure profile = United States or Canada. I would also like to replace the License object with City if possible:
param(
    [string] $path = "C:\Temp\ADUsers-$(Get-Date -format "MM-dd-yyyy").csv"
)

& {
    foreach($azuser in Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true') {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            "Employee ID"   = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]
            "First Name"    = $azuser.surname
            "Last Name"     = $azuser.givenName
            "Work Email"    = $azuser.UserPrincipalName
            "Job Title"     = $azuser.JobTitle
            "Department"    = $azuser.CompanyName
            "Manager Email" = (Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $azuser.ObjectId).UserPrincipalName
            "License"       = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["extension_a92a_msDS_cloudExtensionAttribute1"]
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV -Path $path -NoTypeInformation


Thank you!
I am currently using the script as is, but it is pulling many additional users across regions which I do not need to see details for.

I also tried simply replacing the 'accountEnabled eq true' statement with: 'CountryOrRegion eq US' along with other variations with/without parenthesis eq vs. -eq , and I just run into syntax errors.

For filtering the Azure-Entra ID, User-ID profile based on Country/Region, I used this below modified script:
param(
    [string] $path = "C:\Users\XXXX\YYYY\ZZZZ\CanadaUSAUser-$(Get-Date -format 'MM-dd-yyyy').csv"
)
 
 Connect-AzureAD
 
$userData = @()
 
foreach ($azuser in Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter "accountEnabled eq true" | Where-Object { $_.Country -eq "United States" -or $_.Country -eq "Canada" }) {
    $manager = Get-AzureADUserManager -ObjectId $azuser.ObjectId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $managerEmail = if ($manager) { $manager.UserPrincipalName } else { "" }
 
    $userData += [pscustomobject]@{
        "Employee ID"   = $azuser.ExtensionProperty["employeeId"]
        "First Name"    = $azuser.surname
        "Last Name"     = $azuser.givenName
        "Work Email"    = $azuser.UserPrincipalName
        "Job Title"     = $azuser.JobTitle
        "Department"    = $azuser.CompanyName
        "Manager Email" = $managerEmail
        "City"          = $azuser.City
        "Country"       = $azuser.Country
    }
}
 
$userData | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation



Output:

